# How can I align a value with leading zero or in general?

Tags: c, formatting, integer, justify

First off I just want to say that I am a beginner to programming and therefore many of the solutions to my problem that I have seen are too complicated for me to understand.
I was given a task to write a program which will get the date by using scanf function in dd-mm-yyyy format and show it with printf in a column like this:

```
Day:     dd
Month:   mm
Year:  yyyy
```

The problem with 0 I solved by adding '02' or '04' to %d. However, the main problem is that the date needs to be displayed with numbers being aligned to the right. My code looks like this:

```
int a,b,c;
printf("Enter the date\n");
scanf("%2d-%2d-%4d", &a, &b, &c);
printf("Day: %02d \nMonth: %02d \nYear: %04d" ,a,b,c);
return 0;
```

and I don't know how to align those numbers as I saw that in order to do that you must have no numbers in %d, which is problematic. The task says that I can't use space, loops, switch, if and have to do it with one scanf and two printf. I will be forever grateful for anyone who will help me with this issue or at least give me a clue what should I do, because I am out of options.

Comment: Just put the spaces in the format string. I don't know what this assignment is trying to teach you otherwise.

Comment: @Cheatah The system to which I have to upload the code detects if I used spaces and automatically reject my work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
printf("%-9s%02d\n%-9s%02d\n%-7s%04d\n", "Day:", a, "Month:", b, "Year:", c);
```

I removed your unnecessary (and faulty) space before each `\n` newline, and added a final newline.

The `%-9s` left-formats a string in spaces total width 9.
The `%02d` right-formats an `int` in zeros total width 2.

You can read about [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160). There is a lot of detail to take in.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much, I can even understand this line.

Comment: Please show your thanks by "accepting" this answer. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?